# sealert takes very long on centos7

Tags: centos, selinux

I'm trying to human read `/var/log/audit/audit.log` file on centos7. I came with command

```
sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

which works fine on one machine, there is initial scan which takes second or so, but on another one scan goes on for about 30 minutes and is still on 40%. It cannot be stopped by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>. I also tried to remove `audit.log` so it's almost empty but there was no speedup.

Both of these machines are virtual and run on same host

I found out that many alerts were generated by my apache, so I disabled selinux using

```
setenforce 0
```

and removed old `audit.log.X` files but its still same slow (and keeps slowing so it might never finish) `sealert` process is using one core permanently at 25% of CPU and 1gig of RAM.

is there any other way I can analyze selinux log files from cli ?

Comment: Yes, pipe your audit.log to `audit2allow` to see what rules or booleans it would suggest enabling or creating.  That should return almost instantly.